# Не работает Raycast

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хотел создать небольшой проект на Unity и для этого нужны мне рэйкасты. При попытке создать их, точнее даже при создании одного, рэйкаст не выдаёт дистанцию при столкновении с объектом, он просто проходит сквозь него, подскажите что делать. Объект в который сталкивается, был вначале обычным спрайтом, потом стал 3D кубом который я растянул по оси Z, чтобы уж точно было, и всё равно значение рэйкаста: 0.
Вот код самого контроллера игрока:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1.0f;
    private float speedX = 0.0f;
    private float speedY = 0.0f;
    private float health = 20.0f;
    Ray2D ray1;

    private void Update()
    {
        ray1 = new Ray2D(transform.position + transform.TransformVector(0f,0.6f,0), transform.up);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray1.origin, ray1.direction);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(Physics2D.Raycast(ray1.origin,ray1.direction).distance);
        speedX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        speedY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        transform.position += transform.up * speed * speedY * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.forward, -speedX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[image: Скриншот сцены и консоли в Unity]

Answer (score 0):

Я так думаю, что проблема заключается в том, что на ваш кубик не навешен Box Collider, из-за этого raycast просто не видит кубик.

Comment: Нет, коллайдер на нём есть и сделан ровно в размер куба

Comment: @YukioIto, попробуйте в своём коде поменять Ray2D на Ray.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: Ray2D заменить на Ray и Physics2D на Physics. Не используйте 2Д-физику с 3Д-коллайдерами!

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, теперь заработало